# My python code does not run the next line

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to make some quiz programs but my code is stuck in input()

```
print("나라 퀴즈에 오신 여러분들을 환영합니다!\n이 퀴즈에서 여러분들은 국기를 보고 나라 이름을 맞추시면 됩니다!")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("\n1. 아메리카\n2. 아프리카\n3. 유럽\n4. 아시아\n5. 오세아니아\n6. 모든 나라\n")
continent=input("어느 대륙의 퀴즈를 맞출 건지 선택해주세요: ")

if(continent==1):
    quizamerica()
```

my code does not run after line `if(continent==1)` and just stops the program after line `continent=input("어느 대륙의 퀴즈를 맞출 건지 선택해주세요: ")`

Help me please.

Comment: python2 or python3? use `raw_input` in python2

Comment: I'd advise you to print the value of `continent` to make debugging easier. But my guess is that perhaps continent is a string and `"1"==1` is `False`

Comment: @ingvar or even better, just use python 3. Note, if you use raw_input in python 2, it will fail like if you use input in python 3... they are equivalent.

Comment: `input` returns the inputted string. I think you are trying to check if there was an input... you can check the length of `continent` rather than checking if it is equal to `1`.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debugger? Code seems fine to me

Comment: thanks for all you guys. I could finally solve this problem thanks to all of you

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` function returns a string. Try `if(continent == '1')`.

Comment: Or, better yet, `if continent == '1':` since python syntax doesn't require `()` here.

Comment: thank you! I could finally solved this problem really really thanks to you